# How do you set a parameter in a method that will work inside an array? (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm trying to make a method that has a parameter that can be used to specify the index of the array.

I used

```
var doc =  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var paragraph = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();

function Parry(indx) {
    paragraph[indx].getText();
  }

body.appendParagraph(Parry(2));
```

And originally in the document was a bunch of words that went down

yellow
red
orange
purple

And then it said undefined

Comment: "And then it said undefined"... what value did you pass it to get undefined? Was it a valid index?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Just run testParry().

```
function Parry(indx) {
  var doc =  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var paragraph = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  return paragraph[indx].getText();
}

function testParry() {
  Logger.log(Parry(2));
}
```

Comment: But why does adding return change it?

Comment: Without return nothing is returned to the calling function. But the problem I was seeing was that paragraph was not defined in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Although Cooper answer is not wrong I would like to address the main problems here.

First of all you lack a `return` statement from the main function, if `return` is not used then your variable completely  "empty" and then `"undefined"` will be added as paragraph.

```
function Parry(indx) {
  paragraph[indx].getText();
}
Logger.log(Parry(2)); // undefined
```

But adding `return` makes it a "valid" value.

```
function Parry(indx) {
  return paragraph[indx].getText();
}
Logger.log(Parry(2)); // <Your text in 3rd paragraph>
```

Also I don't know if some code is missing from your post but the variable `body` is not defined. Adding it make your code work perfectly for me.

```
var doc =  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var paragraph = body.getParagraphs();

function Parry(indx) {
  return paragraph[indx].getText();
}

body.appendParagraph(Parry(2));
```

---

A note on one Cooper's comment.

> But the problem I was seeing was that paragraph was not defined in the function.

There is partially true, if there is no reason to make your variables global, create them as locals (inside the functions). But there could be reasons on why you want to create the variables as global.

Take a look at [JavaScript scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)